# SharePoint follow documents Rest API not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, follow

I have been using SharePoint online rest end point to get users followed documents. The end point is 
{sitepath}/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=2)

I was able to get follow docs in the response but from last couple of hours, this end point has stopped working and not receiving the docs in response. Is there one else facing similar issue or know about any outage on Microsoft side ?

Regards,
Tayyab

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest that you contact MS support for the same.

Having said that, Microsoft mentioned in the blog that they were deprecating the social APIs. Looks like a fallout of this. But better to confirm this with Microsoft support.

Reference - [Upcoming API changes to SharePoint social feed APIs and following](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/upcoming-api-changes-to-sharepoint-social-feed-apis-and-following/)

What Microsoft is suggesting is to use the Graph APIs (in beta).

Follow site - [Follow site graph API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-follow?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Follow documents - [Follow files graph API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-list-following?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Comment: Thank you very much @Gautam for sharing the article, it was helpful. I will contact to MS support referring with your shared link.